# Get number from every input in table

Tags: javascript

I have a table, which has an input at the end of each line.

Here is the input:

```
<td><input data-price='<?= floatval($row['Prix']); ?>' ?>' type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity"></td>
```

I have a script that takes the price of the data-price in the input and multiplies
it with the number in the input. Right now my script starts off by adding all of the prices, but then it multiplies the total by only the first input in my table.

How can I change my code so that it multiplies each price by the quantity in the input?

Here is the script:

```
    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function giveTotal() {
        var total = 0;
        var grandTotal = document.getElementById('grandTotal');
        var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
        var nodes = document.getElementsByName('quantity');
        [].forEach.call(nodes, function(node) {
          console.log(quantity.value);
          console.log(node.dataset.price);
          total += (parseFloat(node.dataset.price) * quantity.value)
        })
        grandTotal.innerHTML = total;
        console.log('Total: ' + total);
      };
```

Comment: With forms, you don't set up a `click` handler for the submit button, you set up a `submit` handler for the `form` because it's possible to submit without clicking the button.

Comment: i don't have a form set up right now, i'm just taking the info right out of my table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs are unique -- no two elements can have the same ID. When you use `document.getElementById()`, it will return only the first element that matches that ID and no other.

You already have access to each input from your `nodes` variable, and you're already iterating over them in your `forEach` loop. So instead of multiplying by `quantity.value`, you should just be multiplying by `node.value` so that you're using the value of each specific input.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select each table row by itself like this:

(In this example I assume your table has the id `orders`)

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function giveTotal() {
    // Get the table element (id="orders")
    const $table = document.getElementById('orders');
    // Get the grand total element
    const $grandTotal = document.getElementById('grandTotal');
    // Temporary variable
    let total = 0;
    // For each input element in the table add the price*value to total
    table.querySelectorAll('input').forEach($input => {
        total += (parseFloat($input.dataset.price) * $input.value)
    });
    // Write total to $grandTotal element
    $grandTotal.innerText = total;
    // Debug output
    console.log('Total: ' + total);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get table rows and process them. Something like this.

```js
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
  var total = Array.from(document.querySelector('#cart tbody')
      .querySelectorAll('tr')) //get array
    .reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.querySelector('td:first-child').innerText * cur.querySelector('input').value, 0);
  console.log(total);
};
```

```html
<table id="cart">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>5.45</td>
      <td><input name="qty" type="text" value="0" />
        <!--number is ok too -->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7.80</td>
      <td><input name="qty" type="text" value="0" />
        <!--number is ok too -->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0.95</td>
      <td><input name="qty" type="text" value="0" />
        <!--number is ok too -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
```